# Can't install Python through Pyenv on MAC

Tags: macos, pyenv

I'm trying to install Python 3.9.16 through pyenv but get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 211, in _main
return _bootstrap(
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 130, in _bootstrap
return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 39, in _run_pip
return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True).returncode
File "/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/Lib/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/private/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/python-build.20230508142345.28952/Python-3.9.16/python.exe', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/tmp45llfbar/setuptools-58.1.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/tmp45llfbar/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/var/folders/yv/mbl800td04xb4pd9hctdshd00000gn/T/tmp45llfbar\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: upgrade pyenv or remove it cache and install again maybe?

Comment: pyenv 2.3.17 already installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to this [issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1876)

Python 3.9.0 don't seem to support Apple Silicon. According to release note, python support Apple Silicon from 3.9.1.

SOLVED with:

```
arch -x86_64 pyenv install 3.8.9
```

Comment: Finally I got it work with the `arch -x86_64` thing, after a whole morning trying to fix the "BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.3.1 using python-build 20180424)" error for my M1 Mac. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Plz do the following steps on a Mac terminal:

Execute the command:

> brew doctor

Follow the instructions provided to resolve any potential issues. For instance, if there are gettext files detected at a system prefix, which might lead to compilation and link failures, take the necessary actions to clean them up. These files typically include:

/usr/local/lib/libgettextlib.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libintl.dylib

Please remove them and install any version of python you want. For example,

> pyenv install 3.11.8